# After importing PST file, new mail is delivered into archive folder instead of Inbox

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007

I recently migrated my files(specifically Outlook Archive files <.pst>) from Windows XP on one of my laptops to Windows 7 on the other laptop. Both of the machines have Outlook 2007. My older machines had rules defined to redirect certain mails to my Personal folders.

Here is what I did:
1 > Opened up the Inbox archive file
2 > This created an Archive folder structure in my "All Mail Items" window
3 > I could see all the emails from my old machine under this archive folder.

The issue is, all my new emails that I get on my new machine are redirected to this archived Inbox folder instead of Inbox in Favorite Folder. I did not find any rules defined as well to cause this redirection of emails.

Can anyone please let me know the reason for this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Office 2007: Changing the delivery location:

1. Close Outlook if open
2. [Click] the **Start Button**
3. [Click] the **Control Panel**
4. [Click] **User Accounts** (*Missing User Account? See Note 2*)
5. [Click] or [Double-Click] **Mail** (*Missing the Mail Icon? See Note 1*)
6. *Mail Setup* dialog box should opens
7. [Click] **View or change existing e-mail accounts**
8. [Click] **Next**
9. Select **Deliver new e-mail to the following location list** drop down box
10. Select new the location you want
11. [Click] **Finish**.

*Note 1: Icon won't appear unless you have Outlook installed and have run the program at least once.*

*Note 2: If you are missing User Account that means you are in Classic View. Just skip this step.*

*Note 3: All these steps should apply to Windows XP Vista and 7.*